# Использование шаблонной структуры внутри шаблонного класса в С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, структуры

Внутри шаблонного класса мне нужно создать хеш-таблицу, хранящуюю шаблонную структуру. Но получаю ошибку:
main.cpp:23:33: error: template argument 3 is invalid
Cache_t <int, int, Node>cache;

Код:

```
template <typename T > struct Node {
    T value;
    int type;
};
template <typename T, typename KeyT, typename U> struct Cache_t{
    std::unordered_map<KeyT, U>hash;
};

int main() {
    Cache_t <int, int, <int>Node>cache;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Общее правило - тип, потом параметр в угловых скобках.

Не `<int>Node`, а `Node<int>`.

Замените

```
Cache_t <int, int, <int>Node>cache;
```

на

```
Cache_t <int, int, Node<int>>cache;
```